# WMI Query Date Filter

Tags: python, windows, wmi

I'm trying to read data from the WMI Win32_NTLogEvent class, but I only want to read instances where TimeWritten falls within a date range.

I'm using the WMI module for Python which allows for a pure WMI Query(1) or a parameterized approach(2):

1. `c.query("Select SourceName, Message from Win32_NTLogEvent where EventType =1, Logfile = \"Application\"")`
2. `c.Win32_NTLogEvent(EventType =1, Logfile = "Application")`

The problem is, I can't seem to get either to accept my date arguments. I've tried several date formats including the rather obscure [WMI style](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156576.aspx), and my only success was using the 2nd approach above with the = operator, which doesn't really help:

```
c.Win32_NTLogEvent(EventType =1, Logfile = "Application", TimeWritten = "20110421013749.000000-000")
```

I know I could filter the result set in my Python code, but I'm fairly certain this can be done in the query. I guess I'm just missing something. Anyone have suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code (WQL sentence) which you are using to filter by date?

Comment: I made an edit to include the query that worked. If I try the same as raw WQL I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your WQL sentence is wrong

Replace this code

```
c.query("Select SourceName, Message from Win32_NTLogEvent where EventType =1, Logfile = \"Application\"")
```

by this one

```
c.query("Select SourceName, Message from Win32_NTLogEvent where EventType =1 AND Logfile = \"Application\" AND TimeWritten<=\"20110421013749.000000-000\" ")
```

Note : I don't know much about python (but [i know a couple of things about the WMI](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/)), so maybe you must escape the special chars in another way.